# can i call locationserviceenabled to find if location is enabled or not multipe times?

Tags: objective-c

can i call it like this:-

```
  if([cllocationmanager locationserviceenabled] == YES)

{
      //Againn checking for the status
  if([cllocationmanager authorizationstatus] != kclauthorizationstatusdenied)

     {
          //Againn checking for the status
       if([cllocationmanager locationserviceenabled])

             {
               //Againn checking for the status
             }
      }
}
```

//with this code i am unable to update the location using cllocationmanager

Answer (score 0):

In Preferences you have two options to disable the location services. The first option is a global switch to disable the location service for all apps "[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]". The second option let you disable the location service for some apps but not for all apps.

To check if its disabled globally and if its disabled for your app use following:

```
  if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] && 
  [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
  {
    // here you can do what you want if location service is enabled 
  }
```

Comment: but i am now also getting a problem that is in ios 8 my app gives me popup for location but not updating any location can u tell me about this?

Comment: Try to use [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] to re-start positions generation and [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; to stop in in your tear down code.

Comment: i have got the problem my delegates for the location manager are not at acalled for ios 8 they are working perfectly for below ios 8.

Comment: Then you need to implement the following steps:     1) In your info.plist file add NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription as key  2) After adding go to the class where you have allocated the location manager and add following code below locationManager allocation  #ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
    {
        [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
#endif

Comment: I hope it will help you :)

Comment: and also after adding above code , add following code too if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

Comment: but the thing is in ios 8 and above cllocation manager is not at all calling its delegate methods neither didupdatelocation nor didfailwith error

Comment: you have to implement above steps for iOS 8

Comment: _locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        _locationManager.delegate=self;
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        _locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=NO;
        [_locationManager setDistanceFilter:10.0];
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
    {
        [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
#endif
    
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

Comment: thats what i have implemented its working completely fine

Comment: yes i have implemented all of these steps still not getting location ..
i m getting the popup for the location to allow it but after allowing it no location comes no any delegate methods are called

Comment: Have you added CLLocationManagerDelegate ?

Comment: yes i have added and also declared it to self but no method have been called

Comment: then u need to send me a code , this issue can only be fixed when i see a code

Answer (score 0):

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             //This code is working fine below ios 8 but in ios 8 it is not giving location
                self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init]; // initializing locationManager

```
            self.locationManager.delegate = self; // we set the delegate of locationManager to self.
            self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; // setting the accuracy
            self.locationManager.distanceFilter  = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

            // Check for iOS 8. Without this guard the code will crash with "unknown selector" on iOS 7.
            if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
                self.locationManager.delegate = self;
                [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
                NSLog(@"working fine for the ios 8 and above also cllocation manager is :%@", self.locationManager);
            }
            else
            {
                [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];  //requesting location updates
                self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=NO;

            }

        });

    }
```

This code is working fine below ios 8 but in ios 8 it is not giving location